# Passing command line arguement in tcl script in NS2

Tags: tcl, ns2

I want to create topology through command line argument. I passed the node number in command line argument. Here is my command

```
ns sat-wired2.tcl 30
```

And here is tcl script fragment

```
set var [lindex $argv 1]
for {set i 0} {$i < $var } {incr i} {
  $ns duplex-link $n($i) $n([($i+1)]) 1Mb 2ms DropTail
}

$ns duplex-link $n($var) $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
```

Here is my output

```
 no such variable
    while executing
"$ns duplex-link $n($var) $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail"
    (file "sat-wired2.tcl" line 109)
```

I'm noob in both tcl and NS2. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your *real* problem is that you can't read from a variable until after you have written to it (with a side-order of `$n(1)` isn't the same as `$n1`, which is obvious when you look at it). If you never initialize the variables, you won't be able to read from them. I don't know what you want to have the links running between (the nodes in your graph) but you need to create them first:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $var} {incr i} {
    set n($i) [$ns create-the node-here somehow...]
}
```

Then you seem to want to link them up in a loop. Which is OK by me. The best way to do that is to use a single loop that has two variables (one of which is “mod `$var`”):

```
for {set from 0; set to 1} {$from < $var} {incr from; set to [expr {($to+1) % $var}]} {
    $ns duplex-link $n($from) $n($to) 1Mb 2ms DropTail
}
```

You probably ought to keep the handles of those links around so you can configure them afterwards (to introduce any non-uniform features, such as a varying latency). Maybe like this then:

```
set var [lindex $argv 0]
for {set i 0} {$i < $var} {incr i} {
    set n($i) [$ns create-the-node here somehow...]
}
for {set from 0; set to 1} {$from < $var} {incr from; set to [expr {($to+1) % $var}]} {
    set link($from) [$ns duplex-link $n($from) $n($to) 1Mb 2ms DropTail]
}
$link(0) set-the-latency to 10ms
```

(No, I don't know/remember how to do `create-the-node` or `set-the-latency`.)

Comment: @burro, It's not emphasized in Donal's answer, but the first cmdline argument is `[lindex $argv 0]` not `[lindex $argv 1]` -- Tcl lists begin at index 0.